# autoregressive models vs simultaneous equations models

Tags: vector-autoregression, simultaneous-equation

I know that when the model is a simultaneous equation, you can't always use OLS to estimate the parameters. You will get biased estimators and most important inconsistent. But if all the variables are endogenous, then instead of a simultaneous equation model you'll have a VAR model, and I read that in that case you can use OLS to estimate each equation alone.... I don't understand why you can do this without getting incompatible results. I thought the best solution would also be solving for all the equations at the same time. Why this is not the case?

Comment: "...if all the variables are endogenous, then instead of a simultaneous equation model you'll have a VAR model." That's not correct...

Comment: A VAR model (in contrast to a simultaneous equations model) is estimated in its non-simultaneous representation which allows consistent estimation by OLS.